# How to deal with non-fixed size arrays?

Tags: arrays, linux, assembly, nasm, dynamic-memory-allocation

Today I'm working on arrays and addressing modes so I made this snippet to train myself. Everything is working fine (apparently) but I chose the easiest way using fixed size arrays. My question is about dynamic memory allocation. In my code, my arrays `array`and `array2` have a fixed size (8 * 4(int)). If I wanted to extend them, or to speak with C concepts, make a `realloc` or something like depending on real time values for the size, may I have to implement system calls like `sys_brk` and `mmap`by myself in assembly
or is there an other option ? The other question deals with the part of my code used to reverse an array (label `.reversing`) I know they are faster solutions than mine so if you could give me some advices, it would be nice.

```
%define ARRAY_LEN   8

%macro print 2
    mov     eax, 4
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     ecx, %1
    mov     edx, %2
    int     0x80
%endmacro

%macro exit 0
    xor     ebx, ebx 
    mov     eax, 1
    int     0x80
%endmacro

section .bss
    sumarrays       resd    1
    dynarray        resd    256

section .rodata
    highest     equ     0x78
    evensum     equ     0x102
    sumarray1   equ     0x1e6
    sumarray2   equ     0x256

section .data
    revarray    times ARRAY_LEN dd 0
    strok       db      "Good result !", 0xa, 0
    lenstrok    equ     $ - strok
    strerror    db      "Bad result !", 0xa, 0
    lenerror    equ     $ - strerror
    array       dd      0x33, 0x21, 0x32, 0x78, 0x48, 0x77, 0x19, 0x10
    array2      dd      0x12, 0x98, 0x65, 0x62, 0x4e, 0x3e, 0x1f, 0x3a

section .text
    global sort
    global sum

    global _start

_start:

    ; sort array from highest value to lowest value

    sub     esp, 8
    push    ARRAY_LEN
    push    array
    call    sort
    add     esp, 8
    and     esp, 0xfffffff0

    ; copying array into some another ones : array -> revarray

    mov     esi, eax
    mov     edi, revarray
    mov     ecx, ARRAY_LEN
    rep     movsd

    ; now let's reverse the array

    mov     esi, revarray          ;esi = address of array                    
    mov     ecx, ARRAY_LEN          ;ecx = number of elements
    lea     edi, [esi + ecx * 4 - 4]

.reversing:
    mov     eax, [esi]              ;eax = value at start
    mov     ebx, [edi]              ;ebx = value at end
    mov     [edi], eax
    mov     [esi], ebx
    add     esi, 4                  ;incrementing address of next item at start
    sub     edi, 4                  ;incrementing address of next item at end
    cmp     esi, edi                ;middle reached ?
    jb      .reversing              ;no we continue

.reversed:

    ;after, we compute the sum of the elements in the array

    mov     esi, revarray       ; address of array
    mov     edx, ARRAY_LEN      ; num elem of array
    sub     esp, 8
    call    arraysum            ; sum computation
    add     esp, 8
    cmp     eax, sumarray1      ; we check the result to be sure
    jne     .failure

    ; merging array2 with array
    ; esi = source address of first array
    ; edi = address of second array, the destination one
    mov     esi, array2
    mov     edi, array
    sub     esp, 8
    call    mergearrays
    add     esp, 8

    ; we compute the sum of the merged arrays into the new (old one in fact)
    mov     esi, array
    mov     ecx, ARRAY_LEN
    add     esp, 8
    call    arraysum
    add     esp, 8

    cmp     eax, 0x43c      ; we check the result to be sure
    jne     .failure        ; if not egal, exit

    ; compute the sum of even numbers only in the array
    ; set up edx to 0 at beginning of loop
    ; cmova edx, $value_even_number
    mov     esi, revarray
    xor     ebx, ebx
    xor     ecx, ecx

.iterate: 
    xor     edx, edx                ; setting up edx to 0
    mov     eax, [esi + ecx * 4]
    test    al, 1                   ; CF == 0 ? so it's an even number
    cmovz   edx, eax                ; we store the value of current element in edx
    add     ebx, edx                ; so in case of odd number => add 0
    inc     ecx
    cmp     ecx, ARRAY_LEN          ; end of array reached ?
    jne     .iterate                ; no, we continue
    cmp     ebx, 0x102              ; check if result is good
    je      .success
    jmp     .failure
    exit     

.success:
    print   strok, lenstrok
    exit

.failure:
    print   strerror, lenerror
    exit

; ********************************************
; computes the sum of all elements of an array
; esi = address of the array
; edx = number of elements in array
; output : eax
; ********************************************
arraysum:
    push    ebx
    xor     ebx, ebx
    xor     ecx, ecx

.arraysum:
    mov     eax, [esi + ecx *4]
    add     ebx, eax
    inc     ecx
    cmp     ecx, edx
    je      .sumdone
    jmp     .arraysum

.sumdone:
    mov     eax, ebx
    pop     ebx
    ret
    
; *********************************************
; procedure that sort array from highest to lowest value
; first arg = address of the array
; second arg = number of elements in a array
; return : eax, sorted array
; ********************************************
sort:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    mov     edx, [ebp + 12]

.loop1:
    mov     esi, [ebp + 8]
    mov     ecx, [ebp + 12]

.loop2:
    mov     eax, [esi]
    mov     ebx, [esi + 4]
    cmp     eax, ebx
    jg      .skip

    mov     [esi], ebx
    mov     [esi + 4], eax

.skip:
    add     esi, 4          ;perform loop checks
    dec     ecx
    cmp     ecx, 1
    ja      .loop2
    dec     edx
    ja      .loop1

    mov     eax,[ebp + 8]   ; save result in eax

    mov     esp,ebp
    pop     ebp
    ret

; ****************************************************
; function adding two arrays merging them
; esi = address of first array
; edi = address of second array (destination array)
; ****************************************************
mergearrays:
    xor     ecx, ecx

.merging:
    mov     eax, [esi + ecx * 4]
    xadd    [edi + ecx * 4], eax
    inc     ecx
    cmp     ecx, ARRAY_LEN
    je      .mergedone
    jmp     .merging

.mergedone:
    ret
```

Comment: In C, you can't realloc a `static int array[256]`, just like you can't in asm either.  Either make a huge static array in BSS and only use part of it (which is fine thanks to lazy memory allocation, only a problem if overcommit is disabled in your kernel settings), or use stack space (up to 8MiB), or call malloc / realloc.  Or `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` and Linux's `mremap(MREMAP_MAYMOVE)`

Comment: Your array reverse loop is about as good as you're going to do with scalar code.  You could reverse 16 or 32 bytes at a time with SSE2 `pshufd` or AVX2 `vpermd` with the same strategy of walking pointers in from the ends until they cross.

Comment: Oh, wait a minute, you're copying and then reversing in-place.  That has to loop over the elements twice.  If you want a reversed copy, read backwards and store forwards.  (You can still use SSE2 to speed it up.)  But as an exercise in in-place reverse, sure.  Also, you can sum the array while you're making a reversed copy, while you have the data in registers.  (*computational intensity*, the amount of ALU work you do for every load of the data, is a big deal for modern CPUs with wide pipelines, especially if you aren't cache-blocking for L1d cache size.)

Comment: You don't have to *implement* `realloc` -- just have to *call* it, just like you would in C to manage an enlarging array.